# Usage of GitHub Primer React Components with Octions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, primereact, octicons

From the next example (provided by the [documentation](https://primer.style/components/TextInput)):

```
<TextInput ml={4} icon={Search} aria-label="Zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Find user" autoComplete="postal-code" />
```

I get this error:

> Type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { size: [16, 16]; }' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'ReactElement ReactElement
>   Component)>) | (new (props: any) => Component)>': type, props, key

I'm developing a ElectronJS, React, Typescript application, and I would like to add the icon/octicon to the TextInput (is where the error comes from).

Any idea about how to solve this error? I didn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bug that will be fixed in the next minor release:
https://github.com/primer/components/pull/808

Workaround until release:

```js
<TextInput icon={Search as any} />
```